# NSWorkspace: runningApplications is not returning all user processes unless I use an NSTimer

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, process, nsworkspace

I am trying to use NSWorkspace to get all the currently running user applications/processes. When I run the code below, it only returns a subset of all the currently running user applications and displays them in the tableView. Yet, when I uncomment the timer line, all the applications are returned and displayed in the table. I'm not sure why the first call to NSWorkspace.runningApplications doesn't immediately fetch all the currently running user applications? Thank you!

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
    var runningApplications = [NSRunningApplication]()

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.refresh(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        runningApplications = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications
        print(runningApplications)
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    func refresh(timer: NSTimer){
        runningApplications = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

// MARK: - NSTableViewDataSource

extension ViewController: NSTableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return runningApplications.count
    }

}

// MARK: - NSTableViewDelegate

extension ViewController: NSTableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let cellView: NSTableCellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        cellView.textField?.stringValue = runningApplications[row].localizedName!
        return cellView
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the `print` at the end of `viewDidLoad` print all running applications or the subset?

Comment: To be clear: does the first `runningApplications` always return a subset or does the first call return the full set if the timer is set?

Comment: The first call always returns a subset